# Sum the duplicate values order by date from sql table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I have a MySQL table with rows containing duplicate values of Ref_Nr column. So i want to sum the values of Points with respect Ref_Nr, to u_id and r_date columns.

```
id  u_id     r_date   Points  Ref_Nr
1   1     2018-04-11    1       3 
2   1     2018-04-11    2       3
3   2     2018-04-11    3       4
4   2     2018-04-11    4       4
5   3     2018-04-11    6       2
6   3     2018-04-11    6       2 
7   1     2018-04-10    3       3
8   1     2018-04-10    5       3
9   1     2018-04-10    2       4
10  1     2018-04-10    2       4
11  2     2018-04-10    3       3
12  2     2018-04-10    5       3
13  3     2018-04-10    2       4
14  3     2018-04-10    2       4
```

Here is the my sql query what i tried, but i am not getting proper output

```
SELECT u_id, Ref_Nr ,r_date, SUM(Points) AS Points
FROM my_table  ORDER BY r_date, Ref_nr,u_id;
```

Here is the expected output, please help me to solve this problem

```
u_id     r_date    Points  Ref_Nr
  1     2018-04-11    3       3 
  2     2018-04-11    7       4  
  3     2018-04-11    12      2  
  1     2018-04-10    8       3
  1     2018-04-10    4       4  
  2     2018-04-10    8       3  
  3     2018-04-10    4       4
```

Comment: Read up on aggregate functions here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to group tha data. You can't mix normal column selects with aggregate functions like `sum()`

```
SELECT r_date, Ref_nr, u_id,
       SUM(Points) AS PointSum
FROM my_table 
GROUP BY r_date, Ref_nr, u_id 
ORDER BY r_date, Ref_nr, u_id;
```